# Call a child class from a child class PHP

Tags: php

i am a new PHP, i have some files like this:

In root.php i have

```
<?php
class Root
{
// Some functions here
}
```

In child_1.php i have:

```
class Child_1 extends Root
{
  function abc()
  {
  //Some code here
  }
}
```

In child_2.php i have:

```
class Child_2 extends Root
{
  function cde()
  {
  // How can i call function abc() from class Child_1 here
  }
}
```

Yes, how can i call a function of Child_1 class from a function of Child_2 class.

Comment: Create instance of `Chirld_1` and call.

Comment: Hello, your mean is i can do like this: $call = new Chirld_1;

Comment: Yes, you can do it

Comment: Can you share more any ways? Because i think they are in Root class together, may be will have better way to do this.

Comment: Unrelated naming suggestion: I think the word you're looking for is "child", not "chirld".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As classes that extend one parent (`Root`) know **nothing** about each other (and you cannot change this), you can do:

```
class Chirld_2 extends Root
{
  function cde()
  {
    $obj = new Chirld_1();
    $obj->abc();
  }
}
```

But obviously it's a lack of good design. I suppose, you have to define `abc()` in a `Root` class to make it available in both children:

```
class Root
{
  function abc()
  {
  //Some code here
  }
}

class Chirld_1 extends Root
{

}

class Chirld_2 extends Root
{

}

$c1 = new Chirld_1();
$c1->abc();
$c2 = new Chirld_2();
$c2->abc();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: And i have one more question, please help. if i have class A; class B extends A; Class C extends B; class D extends C.... so, can many of them like that will make slowdown my program?

Comment: This can be checked only by testing, but having such chains usually tells about __bad classes design__

Comment: Thanks again for your helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can  call any function in  class_1 or Class_2 of parent class
but within any child class you can't call  method from another.because They do not have a relevance
a solution is you call class_2 in constructor of class_1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use functions of Chirld_1 from Chirld_2 or vice versa without creating an object of the child class, then one option is to declare Chirld_1 and Chirld_2 as traits of the parent class Root. This will allow you to call functions of Chirld_1 from Chirld_2 and vice verse using the $this keyword. The classes should be declared as follows:

```
<?php

trait Chirld_1
{
    public function test1()
    {
       $this->test2();
    }        
}

trait Chirld_2
{
    public function test2()
    {
       $this->test1();
    }   
}

class Root
{
    use Chirld_1;
    use Chirld_2;
// Some functions here
}
```

See this links for more information about traits: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 0):

Try using parent:: or static:: or self:: notation to designate the class you want to use.
http://php.net/manual/pl/keyword.parent.php

Comment: And this helps __how__?

Comment: yes, thank you. But my English is not good for read documents, so i need a easy example. Can you help me?